# Scroll to element if you do a small scroll nudge or impulse only

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrolltop

I am trying to scroll to an element automatically when the user starts scrolling, i.e. giving just a small scroll impulse or nudge. So when the user starts scrolling down, it should automatically move the page up to the next section. If he starts to scroll back up, the page should automatically move up the page to the previous section. Somehow the code I have so far just moves everything very uncoordinated.

I'd like the scroll to work like this here: https://www.redlinespecialistcars.co.uk

jsfiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ch2Lg6vq

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var browserheight = $(window).height();

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    $('.control-parent').each(function() {

      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var elementOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      var distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

      if (distance >= browserheight - 2) {
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }

      if (distance <= browserheight - 2) {
        // do sthg else
      }

    }); // end for each
  }); // end on.scroll
}); // end document.ready
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.control-parent{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-parent">
1
</div>
<div class="control-parent">
2
</div>
<div class="control-parent">
3
</div>
<div class="control-parent">
4
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML too, and provide a reproducible snippet ?

Comment: done! https://jsfiddle.net/ch2Lg6vq/

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly but it seems to at least be a commonly occuring loop that happens when listening for scroll events and triggering them inside the event listener by animating the scroll position (which bubbles up to `window`). Try this `$('html, body').not(':animated').animate({` as a next step. That should prevent the queueing.

Comment: I rewrote the question a bit as it was not very clear before

Comment: It's a bit hackish but [here is](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMBvEB) a working version. If you want to do this a better way, you could go with `wheel` and `touch` events. Always gets complicated quickly though.

Comment: wow thanks so much for your effort! it almost works perfectly. yet your version crashes once you get to the last element and then keep scrolling down, it jumps back to the first element and then stays hooked there

Comment: Does it? Works [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/t3w74d8f/) when I test it. Could have been a temporary glitch while I was editing or maybe it only happens on a platform I can't check on. I posted a new link because Codepen seems to not be functioning properly at the moment.

Comment: Yea on Mac Chrome and Safari it does not work well at all, very choppy and only scrolls down, even when you nudge the mousewheel up to scroll up

Comment: That is quite surprising. The choppiness makes me think that platform isn't handling the animation well at all (causing the function to misfire at the end), I can't see how the scroll event listener would have that effect. Too bad I don't have a Mac, I'd like to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: just found this: https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify which works exactly as intended. thanks for your help and effort though!